# How to get web page reference using NPAPI?

Tags: plugins, safari, npapi

I have created a Safari plugin using webkit API and the plugin is working fine on Safari 5.0. Now the next target is to run this plugin on Safari 5.1 and as per Apple information I need to change webkit to NPAPI but I am not able to find any documentation regarding NPAPI.

When I run my plugin on safari 5.1, the GUI runs fine but when I try to get the web page reference to get the current Page URL, gets the Page mainframe for DOM to read the html source of loaded website.

How can I get web page reference and URL through NPAPI ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm really not sure I understand your question; you can get the current page URL through NPAPI by using [NPN_GetValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/NPN_GetValue) to get the window's NPObject (NPNVWindowNPObject), then query the "location" property and then the "href" property of that.

You can also find information about npapi at:

- http://npapi.com/tutorial,
- http://npapi.com/tutorial2,
- http://npapi.com/tutorial3, and
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference (official site).

All of that said, you may want to look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org); it'd simplify a lot for you.

Comment: thanks for answer, my questions are 1: How do i convert my webkit plugin to NPAPI plugin? 2: i want to get the page url on safari which loaded. 3: i want to get the whole web page frame so i can read the HTML content of loaded web site through DOM. basically my plugin filled the web page text boxes.

Comment: Converting your webkit plugin to NPAPI is not a question that can be answered on a stackoverflow post; there is no step-by-step "just move this code here and it will work" type of situation. Sorry :-/ However, all the information you need is on FireBreath.org